JIRA Automation Scoring an Issue based on the values of fields
I am hoping someone can shed some light on the apparent syntax error I am getting for the below smart value formula I am using.
The purpose is to assign the issue a priority rank score based on the options filled out when the form is submitted and then subsequently updated.
All the field names are correct, with Story Points being the only build in field referenced
I get this error in the audit log:

Error rendering smart-values when executing this rule: Missing
parameter(s) for operator +u: ( + + + + + + ) + ( + + + ) + ( + + ) +
( + + )

{{#=}}
(
  {{#if(issue.customfield_31600.contains("Will this feed a MIpack?"))}}7{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_31600.contains("Going to the Global Teams?"))}}8{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_31600.contains("Directly impacts customers?"))}}10{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_31600.contains("Result in a cost FTE save?"))}}6{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_31600.contains("Part of controls?"))}}8{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_31600.contains("Forms part of reporting?"))}}10{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_31600.contains("Related to CRM?"))}}5{{/}}
)
+
(
  {{#if(issue.storyPoints <= 0.25)}}9{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.storyPoints > 0.25 and issue.StoryPoints <= 1.25)}}6{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.storyPoints > 1.25 and issue.storyPoints <= 2.25)}}3{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.storyPoints > 2.25)}}1{{/}}
)
+
(
  {{#if(now.diff(issue.created).days < 15)}}1{{/}}
  + {{#if(now.diff(issue.created).days >= 15 and now.diff(issue.created).days <= 45)}}3{{/}}
  + {{#if(now.diff(issue.created).days >= 45 and now.diff(issue.created).days <= 90)}}6{{/}}
  + {{#if(now.diff(issue.created).days > 90)}}5{{/}}
)
+
(
  {{#if(issue.customfield_24404== "High")}}8{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_24404== "Medium")}}5{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_24404== "Low")}}2{{/}}
)
+
(
  {{#if(issue.customfield_15814== "High")}}8{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_15814== "Medium")}}5{{/}}
  + {{#if(issue.customfield_15814== "Low")}}2{{/}}
)
{{/}}

